# change single page to landscape without breaking section

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am using MS Word 2016 to write a book. I have multiple chapters divided by section breaks. Now, within one section, when I try to change orientation of just a single page to landscape, it is dividing the section into two i.e. automatically a section break is added to that page. However, I want to keep this as a single section but just one page as landscape there.

This is because the endnotes at the end of the document have to restart from '1' for every section(chapter), but a section break within a chapter means that the endnotes restart within that same chapter.

I have also tried to format the endnotes for these sections in continuous setting, or to start the endnotes of the section after landscape change from the required manual input. But what ends up happening is that the endnotes of these selected sections start from 316, rather than the required manual input. These screenshots may elucidate the problem further.

[One of the table that is not fitting in portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDgVg.png)

[Landscape orientation change, so far so good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOJfp.png)

[The next endnote before orientation change, '41'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0huW.png)

[The next endnote after orientation change, restarted from '1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTRlb.png)

[When I try to change the settings of endnotes for the specific sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GzZw.png)

Comment: To my knowledge this is just how MS Word rolls. Page orientation is a persection setting, as are footer and header. I also recommend not to use MS word to write large, complicated documents. My frinds master thesis was irrecoverably corrupted after a crash -> 250 pages of work destroyed. Especially not ones that are meant for professional publication, since publishers usual don't work with MS word. Us a proper book writing software or at least learn some form of Tex (eg LaTex). It gives you much more freedom of structuring your documents and takes a lot of the hassle out of formatting.

Comment: This has been asked and answered numerous times – e.g., [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1195793/word-2016-keep-portrait-orientation-of-a-page-but-have-landscape-oriented-tabl). The trick is to insert the table into a text box that you rotate 90 degrees.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll learn proper software like LaTex or Publisher for future use, but had to get this done quickly. The text box trick worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: @cnread I posted an answer with another twist using canvas. Would you give feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Next solution avoids creating a new sections.

- Insert a Drawing Canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, New Drawing Canvas at the bottom of the menu).
- Insert a Text Box inside the canvas (Menu, Insert, Illustration, Shapes, Basic Shapes, first element: Text Box).
- Copy the table and the text you want to rotate and paste it inside the textbox, or directly create them inside the Text Box.
- Select and rotate the Text Box.

In the text flow, a Drawing Canvas works like a figure when either is inserted in a paragraph. You can center the paragraph, add space before or after the paragraph, etc.

If the table does not fit the page, you can decrease the font. You can also play with the margins of the cells of the table.

Of course, you could make a table in Excel and copy it in Word as a figure, and rotate it, but the previous solution has a better resolution to file weight ratio.

Comment: Sure, I guess this would work, and I'm a big fan of drawing canvases. But the answer in the question that I linked to in my earlier comment doesn't actually involve creating new sections; so, as far as I can see, your solution just adds an extra step/an extra layer of complexity without any particular payoff. Instead of just putting a table inside a text box, you're putting a table inside a text box inside a canvas.